# SQL Select based on partial string match from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like the ones below (examples):

Table 1:

| Short | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| TMS | Thomas |
| RBT | Robert |
| ALA | Angelica |
| CNA | Christina |

Table 2:

| ID | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| TMS123 | Johnson |
| CNA342 | Smith |
| TMS667 | Cooper |
| RBT555 | Lewis |

So the Table 1 in this case connects an abbreviation with a name. In Table 2 I have a list of surnames and each of them has identifiers. I want to be able to get the first name of every person in Table 2 based on their identifier. So the output should be:

| FirstName | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| Thomas | Johnson |
| Christina | Smith |
| Thomas | Cooper |
| Robert | Lewis |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases support a `LEFT()` string function, which you can use in a `JOIN`:

```
select t1.firstname, t2.surname
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.short = left(t2.id, 3);
```

You can use `substr()`/`substring()` instead of `left()` if your database does not support `left()`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

This (or something very similar) should work with most DBMS.

```
Select Table1.FirstName, Table2.Surname
From Table1 Inner Join Table2
On Left(Table2.ID, 3) = Table1.Short
```